# Add title to CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view inside a table view. What I want to do next is to set a title to each of the cells inside the collection view.

I have this code inside the ViewController

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
   cell.titleLabel.text = "123"
   return cell;
}
```

This is the cell class

```
class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

}
```

When I try to add a label inside the cell and then use this label to set the title to it nothing is displayed inside the cell.

This is my current stack:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Will the title of the cells be static or dynamic? If they will be static, I would not use `UICollectionViewDataSource` but would rather just stick with interface builder cells. If the titles will be dynamic, i.e. dependent on some sort of user input/different on each device or each appearance, you will want to make sure you set your `collectionView.dataSource = self` in `viewDidLoad`. This would, of course, require you to reference some array of objects that will dictate each cell's title. How does the app look when simulating? The storyboard doesn't tell us much here.

Comment: they will be dynamic. I added a screenshot of the simulator.

Comment: I'm not seeing a picture of the simulator. Can you set a breakpoint within your `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` to ensure it is being called?

Comment: The picture should be there now. I did and yes its being called. Should I create `@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!` in a UIView better because the label is inside a `View` or should I leave it in the `CollectionViewCell` ?

Comment: A couple of things come to mind for me. Is the cell's `titleLabel` constrained to the center of its container in interface builder? If so, the next thing that comes to mind is that maybe you are setting an odd size for the cells. Are you using `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` via `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout `?

Comment: yes its constrained and no im not using CGSize

Comment: Try having your view controller conform to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ` and add `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { return CGSize(width: 400, height: 400) }` and see if you can now see things a bit better. You need to make sure you set the collection view's `delegate` to self though.

Comment: it was the constrains you were right. Thanks a lot if u want u can post it as an answer.

Comment: Not a problem, good luck!